# How to remove standard active class with Angularjs on click of other links?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this:

First link, standard active *(highlighted)* when opening page, hence the *active class*.

```
<a class="button active" ng-click="$parent.Filter = ''" ng-class="{ 'active': Filter === '' }"> Test link </a>
```

Second link that is not active yet, but will be when clicked on:

```
<a class="button" ng-click="$parent.Filter = 'SomeChoice'" ng-class="{ 'active': Filter === 'SomeChoice' }"> </a>
```

My problem: the first link that I shared is active already, so it is highlighted when the page is loaded. That is fine, but when I would click on the second link, *BOTH* will be active, while **I want the first one to be NOT active anymore when clicked on a different link**.

So I have two active links when I click on the second link. I want to remove the active class of the first one when I click another link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove 'class' attribute from your `<a>` and assign the 'button and active class in `ng-class` attribute with condition.

Please refer this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2FpdhoT5u6D5lHt25RdJ?p=preview)

Comment: Can't get this to work, somehow. It's not doing a thing for me.